# \figure creating vertical space

Tags: graphics, paragraphs, document-classes

I have the following problem: say I have three paragraphs of text, and there is an `\figure` command between the second and third paragraph. If the graphics float is put somewhere else (say, at the top of the page), there will be an extra vertical space between the second and third paragraphs (i.e., where the `\figure` command is).

I'm not sure if this is caused by latex itself, or by a bad class file, which in this case would be https://github.com/schnorr/iiufrgs/blob/master/inputs/iiufrgs.cls

---

EDIT: I came up with the following example, based on the discussion with David Carlisle. If you switch to report, it works (equal spaces between paragraphs). As it is, with the class iiufrgs.cls, it breaks, but I don't know how to fix it...

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\documentclass[ppgc,tese,english]{iiufrgs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

The includegraphics is not related to the problem (it never adds space). Presumably (since you mention images moving) it is a figure environment. If the figure floats there should be no extra space at the original point. If you think there is (and that space is not just stretching for other reasons) you need to post an example showing the problem.   

The referenced class is just a customisation of the standard report class so you should be able to make an example just using report and using rule{3cm}{5cm} (or whatever size is needed to show the problem) instead of an image, and add that to the question.

\begin{figure}[t!]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth} % A minipage that covers half the page
\centering
      \rule{3cm}{1cm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
      \rule{3cm}{1cm}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Some caption.}
\label{fig:zkdisk}
\end{figure}

You're absolutely right, it's in fact an includegraphics command inside a minipage, which is inside a figure environment. I'll try to come up with a minimal working example. Also, the three paragraphs are in the same page; if I remove the figure, the paragraphs become evenly distributed vertically. So I'm positive that the graph is causing the problem.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're absolutely right, it's in fact an `\includegraphics` command inside a `\minipage`, which is inside a `\figure` environment. I'll try to come up with a minimal working example. Also, the three paragraphs are in the same page; if I remove the figure, the paragraphs become evenly distributed vertically. So I'm positive that the graph is causing the problem somehow...

Comment: I think I managed to track down the problem to the lines 145-146 in `iiufrgs`: `\edef\orig@output{\the\output} \output{\setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\vspace{0pt plus 50pt}}\orig@output}`.

Comment: @campa ohh well spotted, I was just cutting the file down... Well that's just wrong, so the OP can't do much other than push back to the class maintainers.

Comment: The comment on the line above is also wrong `\vfuzz=30pt % prevent overfull \vbox while \output is active` setting `\vfuzz` does not prevent any box being overfull, it just suppresses the warning, allowing the page to  overprint the page number, or run off the paper.

Comment: @campa if you make that an answer you'd get a vote from me at least:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Glad I could help, but while I was rather sure about the piece of code creating the problem, I can only guess what is _actually_ going wrong. Never looked into `\output` in depth. I would gladly upvote an answer explaining the troubles but I am not capable of writing one myself :-)

Comment: @campa honestly I wouldn't: an answer that says remove that line would be fine (an answer that explained output routines would be a book:-)

Comment: That was amazingly fast, guys, thanks a lot! If one of you creates the answer, I'll accept it immediately.

Comment: @campa ^^^ you should answer (I have more than enough rep already, and you got there first:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The troublesome parts in `iiufrgs.cls` are the lines 142 to 146.

```
\vfuzz=30pt % prevent overfull \vbox while \output is active

% prevent underfull \vbox while \output is active:
\edef\orig@output{\the\output}
\output{\setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\vspace{0pt plus 50pt}}\orig@output}
```

The first line, as David Carlisle pointed out in his comments, does not prevent the box from being full but rather suppresses the warning. I guess the class' author actually wanted to write something like

```
% prevent "overfull \vbox while \output is active" warning
```

and then shortened the comment :-)

The evil part causing the problem is the redefinition of `\output`. I cannot go into the details beacause I do not understand them well enough, but I think that removing that line will not cause any kind of problem. And leaving it there will cause the ones you observed [and maybe others :-)].